# What is the difference between the metaclass Type and the metaclass Class in Java?

Tags: java, class, types, reflection

What is the difference between the metaclass `Type` and the metaclass `Class` in Java?
When should I be using one or the other when programming with reflection?

Instances of the class `Class` represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application, but also reify arrays and primitive types.

I know that as of Java 1.5  the reflection API of was extended to deal with generic arrays, parameterized types, type variables, ... and so on. I assume that is the main and only purpose of the `Type` metaclass?

Is there a reason the distinction between `Type` and `Class` is still kept in the language design other than backward compatibility reasons?

Comment: `public final class Class<T> implements java.io.Serializable, GenericDeclaration, Type, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type` is a more generic concept, of which `Class` is just one kind. Meaning `Class` is a `Type` (`extends Type`), but there are other kinds of `Type`s as well.

For example, `ParameterizedType` is a `Type`, but not a `Class`, as there is no `Class` instance representing a generic type (i.e. `List<String>.class` isn't valid Java). For example `List` is a `Class`, and `String` is a class, but `List<String>` is a `ParameterizedType`, with a `Class` (representing `List`) as its raw type, and another `Class` (representing `String`) as its (only) type parameter.
It can of course be more complicated, `ParameterizedType` for `Map<String, List<String>`, has a `Class` (`Map`) as its raw type, 2 type parameters, of which one is a `Class` (`String`), while the other is another `ParameterizedType`, with its own raw type and type parameters.

There are other subtypes of `Type`, like type variables — the `T` in `List<T>`, wildcards — the `?` in `List<?>` etc.

So a `Type` is the common super interface for all sorts of types in the Java type system - classes, generic types, wildcards, type variables... Types, as exemplified, can be nested hierarchically, forming a tree, and `Class` is a type that is the leaf of such a tree.

Here's the type hierarchy visualized (the boxes under `Class` aren't real subtypes, but logically belong there, so it's a good mental model):

[image: Type hierarchy]

Also note that `Type`s other than `Class` can only be obtained by reflectively inspecting the *signatures* of fields and methods, not object *instances*, as the Java compiler erases generics there. The only thing you can get from an instance is its `Class` (e.g. `listOfStrings.getClass()`), all other type info on the instance is lost.

It may also be interesting to point out that since Java 8, there is also the `AnnotatedType` hierarchy, that mirrors the `Type` hierarchy, but models types with annotations, e.g. the *annotated* parameter type of `List<@Positive Integer>` is an `AnnotatedType` representing `@Positive Integer`, which is a different from e.g. `@Negative Integer` or just `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer which is clear and accurate. But it remains confusing that Class itself also represents multiple kind of types apart from classes, such as arrays and primitive types. It would have been more logical if arrays and primitives would have been subclasses of Type (they are a special kind of types) just like Class, and that Class would not confound different things some of which are not classes.

Comment: @KimMens While you're right that a class (perhaps confusingly) represents multiple things at once, all those things really _do_ have a `Class` representing them. E.g. `int.class` is valid! And so is `int[].class`. Or even `int[][].class`. So arrays and primitives still _are_ classes, just special. But they certainly could have been modeled as their own subtypes of `Class` at least.

Comment: I added a visualization to the answer.